# Create a new class object that's identical to an existing one but does not refer to it

Tags: python, class

```
def _replace(self, **kargs):
    for item in kargs.items():
        if item[0] not in self._fields:
            raise TypeError
    if self._mutable:
        for item in kargs.items():
            self.__dict__[item[0]] = item[1]

    else:
        new_self = self
        for item in kargs.items():
            new_self.__dict__[item[0]] = item[1]
        return new_self
```

I am working with a class where one if its arguments is mutable which is either True or False to determine if the class willl be mutable. This is saved under `self._mutable`. So as you can see in this code, I tried to make a completely seperate copy of the class but it still refers to the old one when I try to call this _replace method.

Comment: You aren't making any new objects anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

```
import copy
new_obj = copy.deepcopy(obj)
```